# Passing innerHTML from View as a parameter to an ASP.NET Controller

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a @Url.Action ASP.NET Method that looks similar to the code below:

```
<h1 class="sidebar-item custom-heading" id="heading-info" href="#">*Dynamically Changing Header*</h1>
    <a class="sidebar-item" onclick="javascriptFunction()" href="@Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new {
        name="Dynamically Changing Header",
    })">Link</a>
```

With The Controller Method looking similar to this:

```
    public IActionResult Action(string name) { 
// operation
}
```

My issue I'd like to send the text inside the h1 tag(id="heading-info") to the controller. It's dynamic because a there's a java-script function that changes the innerText when called, however that shouldn't be an issue. **Ideally**, what I'd want is for whatever text is in between that h1 tag to be sent to the controller whenever that link is clicked. That value will later be validated by the controller.

Let me know if this is at all possible.

**EDIT:**

This link also handles some properties that should not be seen by the user. The new example is below:

```
<h1 class="sidebar-item custom-heading" id="heading-info" href="#">*Dynamically Changing Header*</h1>
    <a class="sidebar-item" onclick="javascriptFunction()" href="@Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new {
        // Does not matter if seen by client
        name="Dynamically Changing Header",

        // Should not be seen by Client
        importantPieceOfData1=@ViewBag.Piece1,
        importantPieceOfData2=@ViewBag.Piece2,
        importantPieceOfData3=@ViewBag.Piece3,

    })">Link</a>
```

So now the controller should look like this:

```
    public IActionResult Action(string name, string importantPieceOfData1, string importantPieceOfData2, string importantPieceOfData3) { 
         // operation
    }
```

Again, all I need is whatever text is in between that h1 tag to be sent to the controller whenever that link is clicked along with the attached server side code that shouldn't be seen.

Comment: It's possible.  There are various ways to do it.  One way is to write the text to a hidden input (using the same JavaScript that changes the innerText) that's submitted with your form.

Comment: @devlincarnate I'd like to keep it close to the URL.Action format, I have some other parameters that I left out and input hidden forms seem a bit insecure.

Comment: JavaScript is insecure.  The client can change anything.  If you want secure, you need to validate on the server side and not just trust whatever is being submitted from the client.  A hidden input is no less secure than any other value being submitted from the client.  If you have JavaScript that changes innerText, that is just as insecure as a hidden input

Comment: @devlincarnate interesting, thank you for your response. Perhaps I made the OP to vague, my mistake. The other params should not be seen by the client, however the one that's being changed by the innerText can be. I'm going to edit the question to make it more clear.